# Strange problem with express app post example.Have different behaviors with curl and fetch (browser api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browser, fetch-api

I have a simple express app,

```js
// index.js
import express from "express";
// create the express application
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// serve static files
app.use(express.static("./"));
// set builtins post
app.post("/builtins", (req, res) => {
  console.log("debug request body builtins", req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

// start the server
app.listen(3333, () => console.log("Start express app"));
```

And a simple `index.html` page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ExpressApp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch("http://localhost:3333/builtins", {
        body: JSON.stringify(["wojtyla", "ratzinger", "madre teresa"]),
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then((t) => t.text())
        .then((t) => document.write(`<h1>Got response ${t}</h1>`));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I start the server as usual: `node index.js`. Then open a browser at `http://localhost:3333/index.html`.

Everything seems to be ok, but when I open the logs of the express app, I check the following:

`debug request body builtins {}`

But I was expecting to receive:

`debug request body builtins [ 'wojtyla', 'ratzinger', 'madre teresa' ]`

The **strange part** in this is that when I curl:

`curl -d '["wojtyla","ratzinger", "madre teresa"]'  "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3333/builtins`

I receive the expected answer in the express app logs (`debug request body builtins [ 'wojtyla', 'ratzinger', 'madre teresa' ]`).

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> mode: "no-cors",
> ```

Which tells `fetch` that if you try to do anything that requires permission from the server (using CORS) then it should fail silently.

Setting the `content-type` to anything that isn't a supported value of the HTML `form` element's `enctype` attribute is one of those things.

Since you fail to set the `content-type` request header, the browser isn't telling the server it is sending `application/json`, so the JSON parsing middleware doesn't kick in.

---

- Don't use `mode: "no-cors",` on the client
- Do use [the `cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) on the server.